# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDrawingMode' of undefined

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

I am using google map drawingManager to write a control class.
But javascript error happened on this line.

```
// Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
this.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDrawingMode' of undefined

Can some one help me how to clear this error?
Thank you very much!

```
function DrawingManagerCtrl() {
    this.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        // drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControlOptions : {
            position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes : [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE ]
        },
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        this.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    });
};

DrawingManagerCtrl.prototype = {
    drawingManager : null,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that particular API, but I suspect that `this` within the event handler function is not the same as `this` outside it, and so you need to use the fact you're creating a closure:

```
function DrawingManagerCtrl() {
    var self = this; // <==== Create a variable for the closure to close over
    this.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        // drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControlOptions : {
            position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes : [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE ]
        },
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        self.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
        // ^ Use it
    });
};
```

`this`, in JavaScript, is determined by how a function is called, not where the function is defined. So unless the Google maps stuff is letting you specify what it should use for `this` in the event callback, `this` won't refer to your object. By using a closure, you can use a variable (`self`, in the above), instead.

Further reading (on my anemic little blog):

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)
- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might have made mistake in attaching the libraries in the google map api.

Please make sure you have added the geometry library into the script file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry,drawing"></script>
```